# Bootstrap Navbar Too Large for Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I have a website up at https://beta.redxtech.ca and I have a bootstrap navbar with a pulled-left brand and a pulled-right navbar ul.

The problem is that the navbar extends out larger than the page actually is, creating overflow and scolling.

If I could get some help removing the overflow without sacrificing the navbar-brand and navbar-pills on the same line that would be great!

I am also using [santize.css](http://beta.redxtech.ca/sass/sanitize.css) if that makes difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.navbar-right` is meant to be on a descendant of an element with `.container` or  `.container-fluid`. Without this, `.navbar-right` extends past the edge of it's ancestor elements. When one of those ancestor elements is `body`, it causes the page to be wider than the view.

Check out this [navbar example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/) and bring your code inline with what is demonstrated there.

Comment: That fixed the problem. I just moved the ul into the container-fluid with the a. Don't know why it wasn't in there in the first place. Thanks :)